# Find harmonic function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

Find harmonic function in $U=[0,\pi]^2\subset R^2$ such that
\begin{cases}
u(x,0)=3\sin(x)+7\sin(17x)\\
u(x,\pi)=0\\
u(0,y)=\sin(3y)+17\sin(7y)\\
u(\pi,y)=0
\end{cases}

I tried to use separation of variables and look for solution in form 
$$u(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$$
But I don't know how to satisfy 1. and 3. condition.

Answer (score 1):

Harmonic functions satisfy $\Delta u = 0$. Let $u(x,y) = X(x) Y(y)$ then $X'' Y + X Y'' = 0$. Rearranging, $X''/X = - Y''/Y = C$ where $C$ is a constant.

Consider first $C > 0$, and define $\mu^2 = C$, then $X'' - \mu^2 X = 0$. Solving yields $X(x) = A \sinh [\mu (\pi - x)]$. Similarly $Y(y) = B\sin \mu y$. Plugging in the boundary condition $Y(\pi) = B \sin \mu \pi = 0$ implies that $\mu_n = n$ for $n \in \mathbb Z$. Hence a solution is given by
$$ u(x,y) = \sum_n A_n \sinh[n(\pi - x)] \sin n y. $$
Plugging in the condition $u(0,y)$ implies that $A_n = 0$ unless $n = 3,7$, hence
$$ u(x,y) = \frac{\sinh[3(\pi-x)]}{\sinh 3\pi} \sin 3y + \frac{17 \sinh[7(\pi-x)]}{\sinh 7\pi} \sin 7y. $$
Can you finish the rest?

Comment: Try plugging it into the ODE $X'' - \mu^2 X = 0$. Does it also satisfy $X(\pi) = 0$?

Comment: I've done a lot of these before. I know its a linear combo of $e^{\mu x}$ and $e^{-\mu x}$ which can also be sinh and cosh.

Comment: The 0 boundary condition helps me choose which one I want.

Comment: How do we know $X(x)=A\sinh[\mu(\pi-x)]$ is only possible result?

Comment: There are theorems which describe existence and uniqueness of harmonic functions with boundary conditions.

Comment: This may be useful in explaining... https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156505/uniqueness-theorem-for-harmonic-function

Comment: I disagree. The process can also be done by swapping $x$ and $y$ are plugging in the b.c. to complete the solution.

Comment: You're within your right to downvote, I did mention that the OP can finish the rest.

Comment: I don't see where the OP said that, but ok. I see questions on satisfying BC 1 and 3 of which I did one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You can't perform separation of variables just yet. It's not really possible to match both of the inhomogeneous boundaries to the same product, as you have probably tried. What we usually do, is to solve two separate problems, such that

$$ \begin{matrix} \begin{cases} \nabla^2u_1=0 \\ u_1(x,0) = 3\sin x + 7\sin (17x) \\ u_1(x,\pi) = 0 \\ u_1(0,y) = 0 \\ u_1(\pi,y) = 0 \end{cases} 
&& \begin{cases} \nabla^2u_2=0 \\ u_2(x,0) = 0 \\ u_2(x,\pi) = 0 \\ u_2(0,y) = \sin(3y) + 17\sin(7y) \\ u_2(\pi,y) = 0 \end{cases} \end{matrix} $$

You can check that $u = u_1 + u_2$ solves the original problem.

For some more intuition, let's solve the first problem in $u_1$. Separating the variables:

\begin{align} X'' + \lambda X = 0, & \quad X(0) = X(\pi) = 0 \\ Y'' - \lambda Y = 0, & \quad Y(\pi) = 0 \end{align}

which gives

\begin{align} X(x) &= \sin(nx) \\ Y(y) &= \sinh\big(n(\pi-y)\big) \end{align}

where $\lambda_n=n^2$. Notice, the two homogeneous B.C.s on $X(x)$ allows us to "lock" the solution to a specific $\sin$ function. This wouldn't have been possible in the original problem.

So the general solution for the first problem is

$$ u_1(x,y) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \sin(nx) \sinh\big(n(\pi-y)\big) $$

The final inhomogeneous boundary gives

$$ u_1(x,0) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \sinh(n\pi) \sin(nx) = 3\sin x + 7\sin(17x) $$

You can make your own conclusion about what happens here.

The second problem is nearly identical to the first, except the $\sin$ series is on $y$ instead of $x$.